# Too many characters in character literal compilation error

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have this

```
$('#someId').html(<% Response.Write("'"+HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_.T(data.notice.split(';')[1]))+"'"); %>);
```

And I get compilation error Too many characters in character literal

In another place I have:

```
$('#someOtherId').html(<% Response.Write("'"+HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_.T("Something"))+"'"); %>);
```

and it works fine. Why is there a different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only character literal in that line is `';'`. It doesn't look like there is more than one character, but you might have an invisible character in there along with the semicolon, or a tab character that happens to be very narrow at that position. Try to retype that part of the code.

Also look at lines nearby. The line number reported might be slightly off.

Comment: But if I put the ";" instead of ';' I get that data does not exist in the current context.

Comment: @Srcee: It should be a character, not a string, but you somehow got something more than the semicolon in the character literal. The fact that changing it to a string doesn't work indicates that there is another character there, so the `Split` doesn't find that string and returns an array with only one item.

Answer (score 0):

try moving  `data.notice.split(';')[1]` to separate lines.

```
string [] plainTextArray = data.notice.split(';');
string plainTexttoEncode;

//check plainTextArray has something that can be used
...

plainTexttoEncode = plainTextArray[1];
$('#someId').html(<%Response.Write("'"+HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(_.T(plainTexttoEncode)+"'"); %>);
```

the inline `split(';')` is probably confusing the complier.